# How do I remove plot legends using R's ggplot2 package and the opts() function or theme() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am studying R programming by following the Discovering Statistics Using R by Andy Field.
Chapter 4: Exploring Data with Graphs includes examples of plots (using data from discoveringstatistics.com: e.g., Facebook Narcissism, Chick Flick, etc.) where I would like to remove the plot legends.

The book suggests using `opts(legend.position = "none")` command to accomplish this; however, this command does not remove the legend on my plot.

I tried using `theme(legend.position = "none")` function instead as `opts()` might have been deprecated in newer versions of R Studio. Below is the code I executed, but was unsuccessful at removing the legend:

```r
chickFlick <- read.delim("http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/docs/ChickFlick.dat", header = TRUE)

chickFlickBar <- ggplot(chickFlick, aes(film, arousal, fill = film))
chickFlickBar +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "Film", y = "Mean Arousal", fill = "Gender") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: `opts` is deprecated for `ggplot2`, but `theme` is still alive and well. There are many ways to remove a legend, one of which is the one you used. Right now, it's removing the legend for the trace that adds the `errorbars`. However, that still leaves the legend for the colors. One way to remove the color legend is to add `show.legend = F` to the first `stat_summary` call.

Comment: show.legend = FALSE worked! Thank you so much, Kat. You're awesome! :)

Comment: You're missing a `+` at the end of the second `stat_summary()` line.

Comment: Thanks for catching this! I have a + in my script on my computer, but I made a transcription error. With a +, it didn't remove the legend. As Kat said, I was only removing it from 'stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2)'.